# MainActivity.java errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im getting trouble compiling a simple hello world app.

I am getting errors in my mainActivity.java file and not sure whats wrong.

This was created by Eclipse.

R. is coming up as an error when trying to compile/Run.

Here are the errors shown in the compiler:

[image: errors]

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @brso05 there is no stack trace. It won't compile..."Im getting trouble compiling "

Comment: R. is underlined as the error.

Comment: @user3411002 make sure you don't have any errors in **any** xml files and try cleaning/rebuilding your project

Comment: @brso05 ok, just trying to help you out. user3411002 have you **[looked at any of these posts yet](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=R+error+%5Bandroid%5D)**

Comment: try to add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0' dependency

Comment: @vang how do i add this

Comment: @user3411002 in your gradle file in dependencies section

Comment: @Vang the OP is most likely not using gradle because...eclipse

Comment: Am using eclipse yes.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps :-
1- Right click on project >Build Path >configure build path
2-libraries > Remove Android Dependencies.

Comment: its all here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519059/first-time-android-application-errors

Comment: Go to Android Dependencies and remove appcompat_v7.jar                  then Clean And build