# First time android application errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So this is the first time ive used eclipse and android and am just trying to create a project.

I went through the steps to create a new android project to create a simple helloworld apk to use on my phone.

I have not added any code myself yet there are many errors and nothing will compile. I dont know what to do can someone help please. here is all the code and errors.

Mainactivity.java

```
    package com.rikin.myfirstapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rikin.myfirstapplication.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:
[image]

Also get this:

[image]

Comment: do you have a library in your project called appcompat v7? in your workspace?

Comment: i think so, i do have it./

Comment: goto your libs and delete the v7..the right click on the v7 appcompat project and click properties and click android check if the project's build target is not less than 16 or so.. re-import it to your project, copy the v7 jar from the v7 folder from its lib folder and add it to your project right click on the jar and add it to build path clean and rebuild.. and let me know if it helped

Comment: still getting the errors in console, and getting these errors as well http://puu.sh/cne9W/6a8a202828.png

Comment: wow create a new project and a new workspace alltogether

Comment: I've tried that three times yet still getting errors everywhere. I havent even touched the code its just all default code giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Properties` -> `Android` -> add `appcompat_v7` library.

[image]

Comment: Doesnt give me the option for this library :( argh all this is annoying me

Comment: probably you have to download it : https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: The library is already set. i dont think this would solve the problem.s